# How to fix/avoid java.io.IOException: Socket read failed?

Tags: java, angularjs, apache, tomcat, httpd.conf

We are having an application which makes frequent ajax calls to the servlet. We are getting the below exception inconsistently.

```
20:39:15.016 com.abc.xyzhome.util.XYZLog:XYZDashboardServlet::buildXYZDashboardRequest::Exception:
java.io.IOException: Socket read failed
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:313)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.readMessage(AjpProcessor.java:364)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.receive(AjpProcessor.java:331)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.refillReadBuffer(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:664)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:1142)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadChars(InputBuffer.java:353)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.substract(CharChunk.java:439)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:416)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader.read(CoyoteReader.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader.readLine(CoyoteReader.java:163)
        at com.abc.xyzhome.XYZDashboardServlet.buildXYZDashboardRequest(XYZDashboardServlet.java:456)
```

This is exception is occurring sometimes when we are trying to read data from the inputStream. PFB, the place where this exception is occurring.

```
        try {
             BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                jb.append(line);
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

We are getting the `BufferedReader` object from the `HttpServletRequest`. The Exception is occurring in `reader.readLine()`.

Our application is hosted in Tomcat 7.0.54. PFB, the angularJS ajax call we are making from the client for this particular request.

```
$http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'XYZDashboard',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      data: {'xyzStatus':fav_value,'xyzRequestType':'getDataForXYZDashboard'},
      cache: false,
    }).success(function (data) 
    {
        //Some code here
    });
```

The Content type is JSON. Please let me know on how to avoid this exception. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I have tried `BufferedReader ready()` to check whether the stream is ready to be read but it is always returning false. I read in a blog that in Tomcat, ready() always returns false. Please advice.

Comment: Could the inputstream be big? Will the load on the server be high? Could be a connection timeout.

Comment: The input stream isn't that big. This exception is not consistent. It is happening very rarely. Even if we try to reproduce this with the same user (same request) it doesn't happen frequently. I guess network latency also might be one of the factors I guess.

Comment: Size of the stream was just one affecting factor. Number of requests is another big factor. Context switching among threads is very expensive. If there are multiple requests, multiple threads would be spawned increasing the number of context switches if the server has minimal number of cores. Handling a timeout would be ideal.

Comment: Re your edit, there is no point whatsoever in calling `ready()`. Just block in the read method. The actual problem here is Apache AJP's useless error message. They should have printed the error message from the original exception.

Answer (score -3):

Wrap your code in a try / catch that throws IOException

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have already wrapped the code in a try-catch block. We are checking whether if there is anyway to avoid or fix this exception.

Comment: The compiler would have enforced a checked exception at readLine() of a BufferedReader.

Comment: And this will accomplish exactly what? OP already has a stack trace. What he needs is a *solution.*

Comment: OP edited his original post to include the wrapper I added as answer. While I admit that as @Prasanna suggested the IDE would have caught my suggestion give me a little break. He didnt implicitly state he had properly wrapped it so I offered it as a suggestion. Its was my first answer on StackOverFlow, thanks for the warm welcome to the community!